# Why is this NSNumber sum throwing back an odd result?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sum, nsnumber

I am making an app that deals with calculating money and have read that its always best to use NSNumber for this. So I have changed my float values to NSNumber but now I get the following odd result and I don't know why it is occurring.

This is the code:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber*) subtotal {
    NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"subtotal initially set at %@",subtotal);
    for (NSManagedObject *object in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        NSLog( @"Looping");
        NSDecimalNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"total"];
        NSLog(@"object row total number = %@",objectRowTotalNumber);
        subtotal = [subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:objectRowTotalNumber];

        NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@", subtotal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output in the log:

```
**2011-10-19 09:27:19.289 Market[4240:b603] subtotal initially set at 0**

**2011-10-19 09:27:19.290 Market[4240:b603] Looping**

**2011-10-19 09:27:19.291 Market[4240:b603] object row total number = 5**

**2011-10-19 09:27:19.292 Market[4240:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000244200806570181766106054656**
```

Would anyone know what is causing the odd result when the subtotal should simple be set to 5?

**Latest Test** : The NSDecimalNumberMethod works only on new objects that I add in the session, but not on objects that are loaded

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog(@"I'm in ViewDidAppear");
// Reload subtotal via float method
[self subtotal];
//Reload subtotal via decimal method
[self subtotalDec];
}
```

Calculating with float method

```
-(float) subtotal {
NSLog(@"I'm in subtotal using floats");

float subtotal = 0;
NSLog(@"subtotal initially set at %@",subtotal);
for (NSManagedObject *object in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
NSLog( @"Looping");
NSNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"total"];
NSLog(@"object row total number = %@",objectRowTotalNumber);
float objectRowTotal = [objectRowTotalNumber floatValue];
subtotal = subtotal + objectRowTotal;
}
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %f", subtotal);
return 0;
}
```

Calculating with NSDecimal Number Method

```
- (NSDecimalNumber*) subtotalDec {
NSLog(@"I'm in subtotal using NSDecimalNumber");
NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
NSLog(@"subtotal initially set at %@",subtotal);
for (NSManagedObject *object in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
NSLog( @"Looping");
NSDecimalNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"total"];
NSLog(@"object row total number = %@",objectRowTotalNumber);
subtotal = [subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:objectRowTotalNumber];
}
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@",subtotal);
return 0;
}
```

log for view Will appear

```
2011-10-19 11:19:01.506 Market[961:b603] I'm in ViewDidAppear
2011-10-19 11:19:01.506 Market[961:b603] I'm in subtotal using floats
2011-10-19 11:19:01.507 Market[961:b603] subtotal initially set at (null)
2011-10-19 11:19:01.508 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.508 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 4
2011-10-19 11:19:01.509 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.509 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 1
2011-10-19 11:19:01.509 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.510 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 10
2011-10-19 11:19:01.510 Market[961:b603] Subtotal: 15.000000
2011-10-19 11:19:01.510 Market[961:b603] I'm in subtotal using NSDecimalNumber
2011-10-19 11:19:01.511 Market[961:b603] subtotal initially set at 0   
2011-10-19 11:19:01.511 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.511 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 4
2011-10-19 11:19:01.512 Market[961:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000244200806569055866199212032
2011-10-19 11:19:01.512 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.512 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 1
2011-10-19 11:19:01.513 Market[961:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000488401613129104533143683072
2011-10-19 11:19:01.513 Market[961:b603] Looping
2011-10-19 11:19:01.513 Market[961:b603] object row total number = 10
2011-10-19 11:19:01.514 Market[961:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000732602419703789898877108224
```

log for addbuttontapped: Notice how the NSDecimalNumberMethod works only on the last added value, not on the ones that were entered before the program was started

```
2011-10-20 07:17:03.218 Market[2199:b603] I'm in subtotal using floats
2011-10-20 07:17:03.218 Market[2199:b603] subtotal initially set at (null)
2011-10-20 07:17:03.219 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.219 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 4
2011-10-20 07:17:03.219 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.219 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 1
2011-10-20 07:17:03.220 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.220 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 10
2011-10-20 07:17:03.220 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.221 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 2
2011-10-20 07:17:03.221 Market[2199:b603] Subtotal: 17.000000
2011-10-20 07:17:03.221 Market[2199:b603] I'm in subtotal using NSDecimalNumber
2011-10-20 07:17:03.222 Market[2199:b603] subtotal initially set at 0
2011-10-20 07:17:03.222 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.222 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 4
2011-10-20 07:17:03.223 Market[2199:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000244200806569055866199212032
2011-10-20 07:17:03.223 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.224 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 1
2011-10-20 07:17:03.224 Market[2199:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000488401613129104533143683072
2011-10-20 07:17:03.224 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.225 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 10
2011-10-20 07:17:03.225 Market[2199:b603] Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000732602419703789898877108224
2011-10-20 07:17:03.225 Market[2199:b603] Looping
2011-10-20 07:17:03.226 Market[2199:b603] object row total number = 2
2011-10-20 07:17:03.226 Market[2199:b603] Subtotal: 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897042/adding-nsdecimalnumbers-not-quite-working

Comment: Have you checked if `[object valueForKey:@"total"]` is giving you back an `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: Yes that's the solution! although the total was specified as an NSDecimalNumber according to my object model. I had accidentally fed it an NSNumber. Thanks!! @Orangenhain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get it to work I had to add two lines to the code. This is what I had to do.

```
- (NSDecimalNumber*) subtotalDec {
NSLog(@"I'm in subtotal using NSDecimalNumber");
NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
NSLog(@"subtotal initially set at %@",subtotal);
for (NSManagedObject *object in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
NSLog( @"Looping");
NSDecimalNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"total"];
NSLog(@"object row total number = %@",objectRowTotalNumber);
//This is the start of added code
NSString *objectRowString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objectRowTotalNumber];
NSDecimalNumber *objectRowTotal = [NSDecimalNumber    decimalNumberWithString:objectRowString];
//This is the end of added code
subtotal = [subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:objectRowTotal];

NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@",subtotal);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `[object valueForKey:@"total"]` is giving you back an `NSDecimalNumber`, but rather an `NSNumber`.

Update:

Apparently this was going in the right direction. Therefore, undelete the post, so we can have a properly answered question.

I deleted this, because after writing it, I tried `decimalNumberByAdding:` with an NSNumber, and it crashed. But this was in a OSX 10.7 SDK project, so apparently this gets handled differently in iOS.

Comment: Actually i now think that the problem was not coming from there. When I call `[self subtotal]` in my button pressed methods it works, to an extent... it includes values that I have added in that session to say it that way, not the values that already existed and are showing in the table too. When `[self subtotal]` gets called in ViewWillAppear i get a result like the one you see above `Subtotal: -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000244200806570181766106054656` funny thing is that it just worked when i had it set up with floats

Comment: I have edited my initial post with some more info based on what I am experiencing